# Gmail API to retrieve POP Accounts Email Address

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk, gmail-pop, google-admin-settings-api

Is there an api to get the pop accounts in gmail that are configured. To manage pop account settings i found api in [admin-sdk api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_pop_settings) but i could not found the api to retrieve the pop accounts email address in gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API doesn't currently allow you to get or set the variety of Gmail settings, including POP accounts.